# How to access Onedrive Business via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm working on accessing personal documents of users using the API provided by Microsoft Graph, but I am having issue with authentication.

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth) I can simply create an application, set the right scopes (etc.) and then aquire an access token for a given user - this is working perfectly right now.

Querying URLs like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives works - I get a https://onedrive.live.com drive as a result.

What the API doesn't return is data about a second drive on [https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com](https://%7Btenant%7D-my.sharepoint.com). I have tried accessing this data using the API Endpoint: [https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0](https://%7Btenant%7D-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0) using the Microsoft Graph authentication token. This returns the following error:

```
{
    "error_description": "Unsupported security token."
}
```

How do I access the API of such an Office 365 OneDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0` API is not a Microsoft Graph API and it doesn't support Converged Auth tokens from the v2 Endpoint.

Accessing SharePoint `Drives` uses the same API as OneDrive and OneDrive for business:

```
/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives
```

For example, if you had a team site named "AwesomeTeam" you retrieve a [list of drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_list) for that site using:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/:/teams/AwesomeTeam:/drives
```

Comment: How does authentication work for this API? Can you point me to the documentation?